# How to listen on multiple IP addresses?

Tags: c#, networking, sockets

If my server has multiple IP addresses assigned to it, and I would like to listen to some (or all) of them, how do I go about doing that?

Do I need to create a new socket for each IP address, and bind it?  Can i bind multiple ip addresses to a single socket?  Does IPAddress.Any listen on all IP addresses?  The MSDN library is very unclear on this matter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot bind a single socket to multiple endpoints.  A `SocketException` (invalid argument error) occurs the second time you call `Bind()` for a given socket.

As others have said, you can use `IPAddress.Any` to listen to the IPv4 addresses on the local machine.  However, if you only want to listen on a subset of the available IP addresses, you'll have to create separate sockets.

Comment: No, IPAddress.Any does not bind the Socket objects to all IP addresses if you simply count IP v6 addresses.

The correct way is to create two Socket objects. Then one binds to IPAddress.Any, and the other binds to IPAddress.IPv6Any.

Comment: Good point.  My project is still solely IPv4, so IPv6 was not even a consideration when I wrote my answer.

Comment: var listener = new TcpListener( IPAddress.IPv6Any, Port );
listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
                listener.Start();

@LexLi this will help me to create both (dual stack) right?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, your server never has any IP addresses assigned to it.

Instead, individual network interfaces may be assigned IP addresses. Usually, each NIC gets one IP address, but that's just the most common case.

If you want to control which interfaces are listening for incoming connections on your chosen port, you'll need to create a separate socket for each one.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you assign IP addresses to interfaces, but .NET hides that from you and you simply bind to endpoints.  I'm a bit confused why you can listen on mulitple interfaces with IPAddress.Any but need multiple sockets to listen to specific ones.

Comment: I suspect it's a case of "let's make the common case easy to achieve" by the designers of the framework, providing a useful shortcut.

Comment: Any and IPv6Any can be considered as shortcuts. But you could not ask a framework to provide you all shortcuts you want. I totally agree with Bevan. 

When you play more with frameworks and you start to design your own, you will see it is always hard to make choices.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Did you find out the answer for your confusion ? I have the same confusion too.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to listen on all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, use this code:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port);
listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
```

`IPv6Any` tells Windows to listen on the IPv6 stack. Setting the socket option to false tells Windows to not limit itself to the IPv6 stack, but rather to also listen on the IPv4 stack. The default is to only listen on the stack explicitly specified.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty... ummm.. non-obvious ;)  I assume this doesn't prove a way to listen to multiple IP's selectively.

Comment: This may not matter to most people, but this is only supported in .NET 4 or newer.

Comment: I'd like to mention that using TcpListener.Create(port) creates a DualMode socket for both IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: This worked for me using win32 funcs:

 DWORD  val = FALSE;

 setsockopt(sk, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*) &val, sizeof(val));

Saved me some headache--THANX!

Answer (score 3):

I have worked on it, IPAddress.Any is not the proper way, It will bind any Suitable IP address. In my case I have 2 NIC and I couldn't trouble shoot the problem. When I  added

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, portNum);
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IPAddress.Any will listen on all interfaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx

Comment: Ok, that helps (the Bind method just says that framework picks the address to listen on, which is pretty vague).  But what about if I only want to listen on 5 of 10 IP addresses assigned to the computer?  Do I need 5 sockets for that?  or can I call Bind() multiple times with different endpoints?

Comment: Yes, you one per address, unless you bind to Any or IPv6Any.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN library does seem contradcitory regarding IPAddress.Any.  The Bind doc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx

says that the 'most suitable' address is chosen, but the IPAddress.Any doc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx

says that with this constant the socket must listen for activity on all interfaces.

However, I'm told that it's the IPAddress.Any doc that is correct.

(adding this as an answer since I don't have enough rep to leave comments).