# Socket between C# (With WPF) Server and Python Client

Tags: python, c#, wpf, sockets

I am working on a GUI for a project I have that returns output from a python client . I wanted to test out basic connection between C# Server and a basic Python client but for some reason whenever I run the Python it says **"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"** . I know from past experience that it has to do with probably the server not opening correctly or somehow he cannot connect .But ,I can't wrap my head around what's the problem . I'm pretty new to C# so I took a server code from the internet just for some tests .
I have a main window with a simple button and when i click it i want it to open the socket connection.
MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ServerOn;

namespace GUI243
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           Server server = new Server();
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Server.ExecuteServer();
       }
   }
}
```

C# server :

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace ServerOn
{
    class Server
    {
        public static void ExecuteServer()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5400);

            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                         SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(5);

                while (true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Waiting connection ... ");
                    Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();

                    // Data buffer
                    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
                    string data = null;
                    bool flag = false;
                    while (!flag)
                    {

                        int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);

                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,
                                                   0, numByte);
                        MessageBox.Show("Text received -> {0} ", data);
                        if (data.Equals("end"))
                        {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                   // byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Server");
                   // clientSocket.Send(message);
                    clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    clientSocket.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Python Client :

```
import socket


def client_program():
    host = socket.gethostname()  # as both code is running on same pc
    port = 5400 # socket server port number

    client_socket = socket.socket()  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server

    message = input(" -> ")  # take input

    while message.lower().strip() != 'end':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
        message = input(" -> ")  # again take input
    client_socket.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_program()
```

Comment: You are listening on a _specific_ IP, which is probably a IPv6, _maybe_ `::1`. Consider listening on IPAddress.Any.

Comment: Index zero (ipHost.AddressList[0];) is usually IPV6 and index one is IPV4.  There are alot of other reasons for this error.  Easiest is to try changing index.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept connections using INADDR_ANY on your server.
This means that you accept connections from all the IPv4 addresses on the local machine.
In C# INADDR_ANY translates to IPAddress.Any which is 0.0.0.0.
You can also make the code simpler by using a TCPListener.

[How to listen on multiple IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777629/how-to-listen-on-multiple-ip-addresses/6561315)

The error you get is that nobody is listening on the port. As the port is correctly coded, the ip address must be the problem.

So a small example would be something like this :

```
class MainClass
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5400);
    server.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Started.");
    while (true)
    {
      TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
       ... use client to receive
    }
    server.Stop();
  }
}
```

For code to continue with the client see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-5.0